# Video Upload Applet

Tags: java, flash, video, upload, applet

i am working on a small project that **i need the ability to let users upload a video to my website or use a webcam to record a video and then upload it.** i have seen this done on several sites (youtube,facebook etc) so i know that there is a java or flash applet that supports this. however i have not been able to find one.

can anyone recommend a good flash or java based video uploader with these features?

Comment: to clarify i am looking for something with similar functionality as the applet used on this website. http://www.johnmccain.com/supporters/video-upload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a video upload control different from a file upload control?

Here's a [Flash file upload control](http://swfupload.org/).

Here's a link to a [Ajax file upload control](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti.html).

If you search Stack Overflow for "Ajax file uploader" or "Flash file uploader" you'll get more recommendations.

**Edit:**

Here's a [flash recorder and uploader](http://www.flashcoms.com/products/profile_recorder/overview/).

Comment: but im not looking for just any file uploader. i am looking for one that will allow users to record a video with there webcam. like what youtube or facebook does.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.a8dropzone.com have a upload applet with built in media transcoder (based on ffmpeg so you can feed it pretty much anything)